# c++ - signaling thread using Threadpool method

Tags: c++, threadpool

does threadpool method allows thread signaling ?
what is the right way to control threads in the threadpool.
for example :
I would like to signal a specific thread that a shared memory variable has changed

Comment: Well, that is rather specific to what framework you are using. I would generally use signals and condition variables though

Answer (score 0):

You can use this threadpool in code project
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/637708/Thread-Pool